# Truncate/Delete From on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Im having a problem when using `DELETE FROM myEntity`

I saw on my database that all the entry are gone, but when i tried to insert a previous existed entry, its still have the record from before i delete it.

Here's the code :

```
static SessionFactory session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

public Session membukaSession(){
  return session.openSession();
}

public void clearRencanaPesan(){
    Session sess = this.membukaSession();
    Query query = sess.createQuery("delete from Rencanapesan");
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

So i tried using Truncate

And this is the code :

```
public void clearRencanaPesan(){
    Session sess = this.membukaSession();
    Query query = sess.createQuery("TRUNCATE Table Rencanapesan");
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

This one isn't working at all @@, the entry isnt deleted.

this is the error

`Jun 18, 2012 11:01:54 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
SEVERE: line 1:1: unexpected token: TRUNCATE
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!`

Please help me, how can i truncate or delete all entry.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `delete`?

Comment: @radik About the problem with "delete": This code seems ok, but it won't actually delete the record, unless the delete operation is commited somewhere else. Some of the options are: your database connection parameters are set to autocomit, or your database itself is set to autocomit, or your code is executed inside a transaction (and the transaction is set to commit if no exceptions are thrown) or if you manually commit it somewhere else.

Comment: @axtavt im sorry, my mistake, it should be 'problem with delete or truncate'

Comment: @filipe Oh ya, i think i missed the commit command, i thought that 'query.executeUpdate, means commit too. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The query you've provided contains no error. My first guess was that the session gets out of sync after manually deleting it using the query. [Session.flush()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) makes sure the session is synchronized with the underlying database.

```
public void clearRencanaPesan(){
    Session sess = this.membukaSession();
    Query query = sess.createQuery("delete from Rencanapesan");
    query.executeUpdate();
}
// after you've made your changes and before closing the session.
sess.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks jeroen, i will try this, and see what happen.
Thank you :D